# How to build an index for fast retrieval of data from files?

Tags: sql, database, parsing, data-structures, indexing

I am coding up an SQL query evaluator as a part of my college project and one of the sample queries is of the following nature :

```
select suppnation, custnation, sum(volume) as revenue
from ( select n1.name as suppnation, n2.name as custnation,
              lineitem.extendedprice * (1 - lineitem.discount) as volume
       from supplier, lineitem, orders, customer, nation n1, nation n2
       where supplier.suppkey = lineitem.suppkey
         and orders.orderkey = lineitem.orderkey
         and customer.custkey = orders.custkey
         and supplier.nationkey = n1.nationkey
         and customer.nationkey = n2.nationkey
         and (  ((n1.n_name = 'FRANCE') and (n2.n_name = 'GERMANY') )
             or ((n1.n_name = 'GERMANY') and (n2.n_name = 'FRANCE') ) )
         and lineitem.shipdate >= date('1995-01-01')
         and lineitem.shipdate <= date('1996-12-31') ) as shipping
group by suppnation, custnation
order by suppnation, custnation;
```

Each of the tables in the from clause is represented as a a text file consisting of "|" separated values for each record, the "|" separated values indicate the values of the different fields in the table. The size of the text file is around 2GB you can assume this for every text file. The problem is I want to build indexes to optimize the time spent searching for values and for range queries as in the above case. How do I go about solving the mentioned problem of building indexes so that the retrieval of relevant records is efficient. I am using **JSQLParser** to parse out relevant portions of the select statement.

Comment: Do I understand you right, that you evaluate this select statement with a self written processor using JSQLparser to build an parse tree on which you are working? Interesting! Is memory a problem for index building? Do you know beforehand which columns to index? Are you allowed to use a database to store your file data? By the way I am the maintainer of https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser. Could you share some of your processing code?

Comment: No I am not allowed to use any database for this, I have to perform all sorts of join techniques and also use external sorting to help retrieve data faster.

Comment: How far did you come? Do you have a strategy? I assume you already tried to store the main indexes in memory.  So you could store the row file position there. What performance do you achieve? Do you have some kind of optimizer to achieve a good query plan?

Comment: I am thinking of implementing either a hybrid hash join or a sort merge join using an external sort algorithm to achieve results for such queries but I need some good references for it.

Comment: Look into the sourcecode of apache derby or h2 or hypersql. They all implemented already the stuff you need.